# Net Core 3.0 file upload is not working but it works well in Net Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core

Good night guys, again I ask for guidance.
I have a file upload where the data is sent to the Controller through an Ajax request.
It is working perfectly in .net Core 2.2, but I am having problems with .net Core 3.0

```
<th hidden><span id="m-aloc-freq">34</span></th>
<div class="input-group">
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="selectedFile" onchange="TrataUpload2(event)">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Seleciona..." onclick="document.getElementById('selectedFile').click();" />
                            <button type="button" id="btnSalvar" class="btn btn-primary">
                                UPLOAD ARQUIVO
                            </button>
                        </span>
 </div>
```

My Ajax request

```
$('#btnSalvar').click(function () {
            debugger;
            var model = {
                ParentId: $('#m-aloc-freq').text(),
                Imagem: document.getElementById("selectedFile").src,
                filename: filename
            };

            try {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    accepts: "application/json",
                    url: "/v1/ApiPrestador/Upload2",
                    data: JSON.stringify(model),
                    contentType: "application/json;",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.info(data);
                        alert("Upload efetuado com sucesso!");
                        location.reload(true);


                    }
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(e.message);
            }

        });
```

My Api Controller

```
[HttpPost("Upload2")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Upload2(FotoViewModel model)
        {
            try
            {
                if (model == null) return BadRequest("Arquivo não fornecido");

                var filename = model.ParentId.ToString("00000000") + (new FileInfo(model.filename)).Extension;
                var caminho = _hosting.ContentRootPath + @"\wwwroot\images\docprestadores\" + filename;
                var url = "/images/docprestadores/" + filename;

                model.Imagem = model.Imagem.Substring(model.Imagem.LastIndexOf("base64,") + 7);
                byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(model.Imagem);


                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(caminho, bytes);

                await _frequenciaRepository.UploadDocumento(url, model.ParentId);

                return Ok(true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {              
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

The data I need is simply not reaching the Controller. I already put breakpoint and it is not triggered, that is, the request is not arriving at the Controller.

How can I solve this in .NET Core 3.0?

Comment: Press F12 in the browser to open the developer tools and place a breakpoint to check if ajax is triggered and if there is an error in the console when requested. Please post the code text not the screenshots if you want the community review and debug code.

Comment: @XueliChen I put code text, thanks for the advice. Im trying to do that in Asp.net Core 3.1

Comment: How is routing configured in `Startup` and in your Controller? Where does "/v1/ApiPrestador" come from?

Answer (score 0):

Add `FromBody` Attribute to Controller Parameters:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload2 ([FromBody] FotoViewModel model)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code , the following is the routing configuration of Startup and Controller in my working demo ,please check the difference:

From the ajax url , you should add Microsoft Versioning package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning` with version 4.0.0

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddApiVersioning(o => {
            o.ReportApiVersions = true;
            o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
            o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
        });
 }

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
 }
```

Controller

```
[ApiVersion("1")]
[Route("v{v:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ApiPrestadorController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost("Upload2")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload2(FotoViewModel model)
    {
        //the stuff you want
    }
}
```

**Update:**Here is my [test demo link](https://github.com/SherryCXL/UploadFileDemo), you could refer to.

Comment: Hi @XueliChen thanks for the feedback. I tried to download the demo, ask to login and then say I don't have access. I tried to add that section to my Startup but it still doesn't work. Please, could you tell me more about what I'm missing?

Comment: @Leonardo da Silva Francisco , I tested your code and it have no problem . I don't know the code in other parts of your project, so I share the above code for reference and check the difference. I have updated my demo link. If you still have issues,could you share the demo link in order that we can review and debug?